# Div disappears on hover in IE

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure what's going on here. In Firefox and Chrome, this works as it should, but not in IE. I have a fixed div (firstdiv) that reveals another div (hiddendiv) upon hover. And that div should remain visible as long as either div is being hovered on. However, in IE it's disappearing when you hover over it. Why is this?

I've tried experimenting with different z-index values and positioning, but I can't see why IE isn't handling this properly.

```css
.firstdiv {
background: red;
position: fixed;
left: 10px;
bottom: 10px;
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
cursor: pointer;
z-index: 1110;
}

.hiddendiv {
background: blue;
position: fixed;
bottom: 60px;
height: 40px;
width: 244px;
display: none;
cursor: pointer;
z-index: 1200;
}

.firstdiv:hover + .hiddendiv {
display: block;
cursor: pointer;
}

.hiddendiv:hover {
display: block;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="firstdiv"></div>
<div class="hiddendiv"></div>
```

Comment: Which version of IE browser you are using? It works fine on IE 11.

Comment: Sorry. I should have specified that. I'm also using IE 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was caused by Internet Explorer being in Compatibility View for this site.

Answer (score 0):

When I check in IE, it is working fine.

Not sure which version you are using. Not sure your actual code is the same as the example code you provided here.

Anyways, The below code may help you.

```
.firstdiv:hover + .hiddendiv:hover {
display: block;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I thought this would solve the problem, but this keeps hiddendiv from appearing at all. Would it matter that I'm also using an Animate.css class on firstdiv?

Comment: As I mentioned before this code (even your code) should work well in IE. The issue may be caused by some other code. Could be, because of animate css as you mentioned (you can test by removing it) or some other code that is breaking this one.